# How to create a stacked line graph from one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a csv file that is grouped by month then by date.

The data continues from January 1st, 2019 - October 31st, 2019. I wanted to graph each month (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr... Oct) separately. For each month I wanted to create a line graph that compares the ***day_started*** to the ***num_orders*** columns.

I have loaded the csv into a dataframe with `df = pd.read_csv('orders.csv')`

if I created a line plot with seaborn `plot = sns.lineplot(x='month', y='num_orders', data=df)`, it graphs all months together, but I wanted to create 10 separate line graphs based on the month. Please let me know if I can expand further.

Edit: Code I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('orders.csv')

plot = sns.lineplot(x='month', y='num_orders', data=df)
```

Edit (2)
[image]

Comment: Can you share your code and some test data? See: [mcve].

Comment: @AlexanderCécile edited in the code I have. I am using jupyter notebook

Comment: What about sample/test data? It can just be a super basic example. Reasoning about code without knowing the input or being able to run it is basically impossible.

Comment: `print(df.head(10))` and paste that in place of your image.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I'm unsure how to upload the entire CSV. The picture above is a view when I call `df.head()`. Let me know if you can't see the picture

Comment: @Datanovice just pasted in an edit with the code you suggested

Comment: I can see the picture, the problem is that all the rows have the same `month_started`, which obviously isn't ideal when you're testing a programming designed for 10 different starting months. You don't even need to share the entire CSV, although if you were going to i'd say just stick it on Google Drive.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I posted a complete view of the dataframe. let me know if this helps give a perspective. I wanted to break down the data by month. So for January, I wanted to create a line graph that shows the orders per day. Then create another graph for Feb, Mar, Apr... Oct

Comment: Will Stack Overflow not let you paste data from Excel directly? That would really be the simplest at this point. Or just paste the CSV, since it seems pretty short.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile @datanovice I edited in a direct pic from the CSV file and also changed the `month_started` column to only pull the month

Comment: As it is right now, I have to manually create a line graph by highlighting all the values for the month of 1, then 2, then 3.... I wanted to create a stacked line graph that partitions by the month

Comment: Do you have an example of what your current output looks like vs your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hue=month` in sns.lineplot(...). You will also have to extract day from `day_started`, then make `x=day`. Otherwise plotting with `x=day_started` means you are plotting separate and discontinuous lines.

Here is a short example with a sample data frame to guide you.

Code

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

month = [1,1,1,1,1,\
         2,2,2,2,2,\
         3,3,3,3,3]

day_started = ['2019-01-01','2019-01-07','2019-01-05','2019-01-11','2019-01-31',\
              '2019-02-28','2019-02-17','2019-02-13','2019-02-10','2019-02-07',\
              '2019-03-04','2019-03-07','2019-03-15','2019-03-23','2019-03-18']

num_order = [1,4,5,6,7,\
            8,9,10,4,2,\
            5,6,9,1,3]

data = {'month':month,'day_started':pd.to_datetime(day_started),'num_order':num_order}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['day'] = df['day_started'].apply(lambda t: t.day)

#print(df)
#at this stage the df looks like this

#     month day_started  num_order  day
# 0       1  2019-01-01          1    1
# 1       1  2019-01-07          4    7
# 2       1  2019-01-05          5    5
# 3       1  2019-01-11          6   11
# 4       1  2019-01-31          7   31
# 5       2  2019-02-28          8   28
# 6       2  2019-02-17          9   17
# 7       2  2019-02-13         10   13
# 8       2  2019-02-10          4   10
# 9       2  2019-02-07          2    7
# 10      3  2019-03-04          5    4
# 11      3  2019-03-07          6    7
# 12      3  2019-03-15          9   15
# 13      3  2019-03-23          1   23
# 14      3  2019-03-18          3   18

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
sns.lineplot(x='day',y='num_order',hue='month',data=df,legend='full')
```

Output
[image]